# How to use an array of object Id's to find those objects in another array? Must find all objects based on the given array of Id's

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of object Id's. The contents of the array will vary based on the user interaction, we could have just one ID in the array or 15 different ids (there will never be duplicate ids). How can I use each of these ids to then find the matching object or objects in a different array?

I have tried used filter, includes and find_by. I have also attempted to do nested loops to no avail.

The ids are in an array as such [1, 2, 3, 4]
The objects I am attempted to search through is an array of hashes. The hashes key value pairs are as such
name: Mike Bill
email: "mikeybilly@gmail.com"
id: 5715
What I would like to do is find the objects in this array that have the id of 1, 2, 3 and 4

Comment: It would probably help if you post an example of the array of objects along with an example of the array of ids and an explanation of which object you expect to retrieve for each id (just make sure your example data is brief). Your current examples and explanation are not clear to me in terms of how the ids relate to the objects.

Comment: @benvc my apologies, this is my first time posting a question. I will be sure to make it much more clear. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: No apologies necessary. Just trying to help you get an answer. Hopefully the answer posted by @ZER0 is helpful to you.

Comment: It sure was, thanks for the advice !

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you should have two arrays like those:

```
const ids = [1, 10, 2];
const objects = [{name: 'foo', id: 2}, {name:'bar', id:3}, {name: 'baz', id: 1} ];
```

The actual props in `objects`' elements doesn't matter as soon as they're objects and have `id` prop.

Then, you can create a new array from the `objects`' array, using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
 const filtered = objects.filter(({id}) => ids.includes(id)))
```

This code also use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: @ZERO Thank you very much for both educating on the proper protocol and solving this problem I have been banging my head on for almost 4 hours. From here on out I will include the code in my question! Would you recommend diving deeper into destructing? Thank you again for being so helpful!

Comment: @Algo_Destroyer, you are welcome! destructuring assignment is something you not only useful to write concise code, but if you don’t know it you could actually mistake it for something else (it’s happen a lot). So, yes. I definitely suggest to learn that syntax